# MD5 of entire row in oracle

Tags: oracle

Below is the query to get MD5 of entire row in snowflake

`SELECT MD5(TO_VARCHAR(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(*)))FROM T`

taken from [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008AFmJ2SAL/snowflake-md5-for-row-of-data)

what is the alternative query in oracle to achieve such requirement without having to put all column names manually.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* use the packaged function `dbms_sqlhash.gethash` as described below, but remember:

- the package was *removed* from the documentation (I guess in 11g), so in the recent releases this is an *undocumented feature*
- if you calculate the hash code from more than one row you *must* define order (`order by` on a unique key(s)) . Otherwise the calculated hash is not deterministic. (This was probaly the reason of the removal)
- the columns with other data types than `varchar2` are *converted* to strings before the hash calculation, so the result is dependent on the `NLS` setting.  You must *stabilize* the `NLS` setting to get reproducible results, e.g. with `alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';`
- The column must be concatenated with some special delimiter (that does not occure in the data) to aviod collision: `'A' || null`  is the same as `null || 'A'`. This are *unknown internals*, so it is rather hard to compare the result `MD5` hash with hash calculated on other (non Oracle) data.
- You need extra grant to execute the package

Some additional [info](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2018/04/09/data-hashing/)

**Example**

```
select * from tab where x=1;

         X Y Z                  
---------- - -------------------
         1 a 13.10.2021 00:00:00
         
select
dbms_sqlhash.gethash(
  sqltext     => 'select * from tab where x=1',
  digest_type => 2 /* dbms_crypto.hash_md5 */
) MD5
from dual;

MD5
--------------------------------
215A9C4642A3691F951DD8060877D191
```

**Order Independent Hash Code of a Table**

Contrary to a file (where the order matter) in a database table the *order* is *not relevant*. It would be therefore meaningfull to have a possibility to calculate an *order independent hash code* of a table.
Unfortunately this feature is currently not available in Oracle, but was implemented as a *prototype* as described [here](http://www.db-nemec.com/MD5/CompareTablesUsingMD5Hash.html)